# create runtime jtable in swing

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, awt

I want to create the JTable run time . and it should bind the data from the table of the  database. 
   For Example i want to display the list of all employees from empmaster table and the row and columns should be generated dynamically according to the rows and columns in table empmaster.for static table creation i m using the following code.

```
  try
{

 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsn");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from empmaster");
  ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from empmaster");
  String title[]={"empcode","empname"};
   int c=0;
   while(rs.next())
   { 
   c++;

   }
   Object obj[][]= new Object[c][2];
   JTable table= new JTable(obj,title);
   JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(table);
   add(jsp);
   int i=0;
   while(rs1.next())
    {
     table.setValueAt(rs.getString("empcode"),i,0); 
     table.setValueAt(rs.getString("empname"),i,1); 

     }
    }
     catch(Exception ex 
    {

     ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Create the table at start-up, but update the model later. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Btw, you code does not compile (missing variables, parentheses, duplicate declarations, etc...)

Comment: Andrew how is it possible to create table without passing the no of rows and columns

Comment: @Adeshsingh Just by calling `TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); JTable table = new JTable(model);` and then later you add columns and rows to the `model`. You can also decide to use the [ResultSetTableModel](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch25/Fig25_28_31/ResultSetTableModel.java) instead of the `DefaultTableModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel) to create `TableModel` and just set the model to existing `JTable`.

Comment: Yup or even [this ResultSetTableModel](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch25/Fig25_28_31/ResultSetTableModel.java)